# Selenium Marionette getLocation nullpointer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm encountering:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getLocation(RemoteWebElement.java:338)
```

while trying to get a BufferedImage of the captcha at https://signup.live.com/:

```
public BufferedImage getCaptchaBufferedImage() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  System.out.println("Looking for captcha image");

  this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("hipTemplateContainer")));
  System.out.println("Found image");

  WebElement element = this.driver.findElement(By.id("hipTemplateContainer"));
  System.out.println(element.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
  List<WebElement> childs = element.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
  WebElement firstChild = childs.get(0);
  System.out.println(firstChild.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
  List<WebElement> childs2 = firstChild.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
  WebElement imageChild = childs2.get(0);
  System.out.println(imageChild.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
  ((JavascriptExecutor) this.driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", imageChild);
  String id = imageChild.getAttribute("id");
  this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(id)));
  **Point point = firstChild.getLocation();**

  byte[] img_bytes = ((TakesScreenshot) this.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
  BufferedImage imageScreen = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(img_bytes));
  System.out.println("Downloaded image");

  double d = Double.parseDouble(firstChild.getCssValue("height").split("px")[0]);
  int height = (int) d;
  double e = Double.parseDouble(firstChild.getCssValue("width").split("px")[0]);
  int width = (int) e;

  BufferedImage captcha = imageScreen.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), width, height);
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(captcha)));
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
  return captcha;
}
```

I've looked all over the net, can't figure this one out.. Possible bug in Selenium 3.0? This code works if I skip getting the offset of the image and just hardcode the values in getSubImage()..

Answer (score 1):

I tried for more than 2 hours and guess what? I found the issue.

**Issue:**
It is because `getScreenshotAs` is taking only the visible part of the page (after scrolling to the captcha) but not complete the page, hence resulting in all the issues. It resulted in the Y coordinate returned by the Point (`1041`), is relative to the `complete` web page, but the screenshot image has different Y-coordinate for the captcha (`300`) relative to the partial page. hence resulted in the following exception:

```
java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster
```

> X-coordinate is the same value in both complete web page and partial
>   web page.

so, hardcoding the Y-coordinate to 300 solved the issue temporararliy. BUt the actual issue is that why screenshot is not taken for the complete page instead of jus visible page. may be the bug in the latest geckodriver (firefox driver). tried in `Firefox 49 version with Selenium 3 version, geckodriver v0.1.11 and Java 1.8`.

Following is the code. please try and let me know:

```
    driver.get("https://signup.live.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    System.out.println("Looking for captcha image");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("hipTemplateContainer")));
    System.out.println("Found image");

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("hipTemplateContainer"));
    System.out.println(element.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
    List<WebElement> childs = element.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
    WebElement firstChild = childs.get(0);
    System.out.println(firstChild.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
    List<WebElement> childs2 = firstChild.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
    WebElement imageChild = childs2.get(0);
    System.out.println(imageChild.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", imageChild);
    String id = imageChild.getAttribute("id");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(id)));

    Point point = imageChild.getLocation();

    int width = imageChild.getSize().getWidth();
    int height = imageChild.getSize().getHeight();

    System.out.println("height: " + height + "\t weight : " + width);
    System.out.println("X co-ordinate: " + point.getX());
    System.out.println("Y co-ordinate: " + point.getY());

    File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

    FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("G:\\naveen\\screenshot.png"));
    BufferedImage imageScreen = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
    System.out.println("Downloaded image");

    BufferedImage captcha = imageScreen.getSubimage(245, 300, width, height);

    ImageIO.write(captcha, "png", screenshot);
    FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("G:\\naveen\\screenshot1.png"));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(captcha)));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Following are screenshots saved:

1. Only visible web page is saved.

[image]

2. sub image - captcha image:

[image]

Comment: Hey Naveen, I'm going to look through this tomorrow and post an answer then :) thank you for your time!

Comment: You do also think this a bug? Might file an issue then unless we are both wrong..

Comment: Your answer address another issue that is the one described in the post. It doesn't explain nor address the `NullPointerException` raise by `getLocation`.

Comment: verify the NullPointer exception by loopking at the first screesnshot saved with the name by Screenshot.png (change the absolute path). I have tried in local machine. Suggest you try the code using Remote Webdriver.

Comment: This tells us that though screenshot contains the web page which is loaded along with captcha, we are not able to get the location, so we can confirm that it is a bug. Suggest checking in both local and remote drivers. For local driver, getLocation is working for me.

Comment: By the way, I called getLocation on image image but not its parent Div tag element. Please keep in mind. I'll also what will happens with div tag element.

Comment: The fact that geckodriver only captures the area of the page currently visible in the view port is entirely expected behavior and is **not** a bug. The W3C WebDriver specification, which geckodriver follows, explicitly states that the `getScreenshot` command only returns the current view port. While it's true that the legacy Firefox driver implementation captured the entire page, this behavior is not compliant with the spec.

Comment: @JimEvans, thanks for informing. Is there any solution/workaround to capture a web element which is in a web page, which needs scrolling? As we get Location w.r.t. the entire page but what we capture is the visible page, but we need the Location of the element w.r.t. visible page in order to capture the sub image (in above question) or click the element based on position etc. please suggest.

Comment: Hardcoding the values is not option, as I tried to bring across. Unsure how to continue atm.

Comment: Ok. Does that mean NullPointerExceptiin thrown by getLocation is solved using RemoteWebDriver? Hardcoding can be avoided if we have an option to get the full screenshot or get location based on the partial webpage screenshot captured. That still searching for answer.

Comment: I'll give RemoteebDriver a try.

Comment: Ok. Np. What is the error? Can you elaborate what you tried? Local or Remote? Exception? Browser version??

Comment: Latest mozilla. Still the same error. Tried everything suggested.